# Why are my gradle dependencies in Android Studio not being cached?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, caching, android-gradle-plugin

I downloaded Google's Android Sceneform example project, [solarsystem](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk), under the samples folder in the hyperlink. I intend to use it as a base for an AR Application I need to create. However, I need to take the project to an offline environment.

While I am connected to the internet, the project builds without issue. However, when I go offline, I end up with a

```
No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.4.1-5326820 available for offline mode.
```

I have no problem syncing the project, but I am unable to build anything. I have tried downloading the appt2 dependency from [Google's Maven Repository](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html) directly and including it in my project's dependencies in the build.gradle folder but I still get the same error. My project **MUST** be built offline.

I have also searched online for a few solutions, but none have worked for me so far. I found out that Google did remove the version of aapt2 that I am using, but I was still able to download it from their repository. As I understand, Android should be able to build my project so long as the dependencies have been cached. I am just trying to identify the problem at this point. Why has this one dependency not been cached and why despite including it's jar directly have I not been able to run it?

Comment: Please add the dependency lines from build.gradle

Comment: so I should add the com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.4.1-5326820 dependency directly into my build.gradle?

I thought any additional dependencies should've been automatically added when gradle detects that a listed package requires another package?